# JQuery typing limiter

Tags: jquery, textarea, keyup

Ok first time here and i already have a problem.
I need to create typing limiter.. So when the 0 is reached, user cannot type anymore..

```
$('#text_area').keyup(function() {
    var max_length = 55;
    var area_length = $(this).val().length;
    var remaining_text = max_length - area_length;

    $('#area_feedback').html(remaining_text + ' characters left');
    if (remaining_text <= 0) {
        $(this).css('color','red');
        //what goes here ?

    } else {
        $(this).css('color','black');
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. So what's the problem you're having with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `keypress` event handler.

Like this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6b5h/)

```
$('#text_area').keypress(function(e){
    var max_length = 55;
    var area_length = $(this).val().length;
    var remaining_text = max_length - area_length;
    $('#area_feedback').html(remaining_text + ' characters left');

    if(remaining_text <= 0){
        $(this).css('color','red');

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $(this).css('color','black');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this jquery plugin help you

http://www.stjerneman.com/demo/maxlength-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You should try this out: use KeyPress event and set the maxLength of your text area like mentioned below..

```
$('#text_area').keypress(function(){
   var max_length = 55;

   $('#text_area').attr('maxlength',max_length); //sets the max length of textbox to 55

   var area_length = $(this).val().length;
   var remaining_text = max_length - area_length;
   $('#area_feedback').html(remaining_text + ' characters left');
   if(remaining_text <= 0){
      $(this).css('color','red');          
   }
   else{
      $(this).css('color','black');
   }
});
```